# url redirection issue using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Below are the things i need to convert using .htaccess

1. If url is sample.xxx.com means i need to convert it to www.xxx.com/domain/sample
2. I url is sample.xxx.com/category/34/electonics.html means i need to convert it to www.xxx.com/domain/sample/category/34/electronics.html

3.After converting those things again i need to build request to the necessary pages

I have the following rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/domain/%1/$1 [P,QSA]

RewriteRule ^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$ index.php?domain=$1 [Nc,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/$ index.php?domain=$1 [Nc,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/news/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\.html$ news.php?domain=$1&category=$4&news=$3 [Nc,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/category/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\.html$ category.php?domain=$1&category=$2 [Nc,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/gallery/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\.html$ gallery.php?domain=$1&category=$2 [Nc,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/video/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\.html$ video.php?domain=$1&category=$2 [Nc,L]
```

But it fails

If i change line 4 to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/domain/%1/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

means it will work but the browser shows the reconstructed url.

Anyone spot my error please.

Comment: have you enabled `mod_rewrite` on your webserver?

Comment: On Apache, the directory config have the entry `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: yes i enabled and tested with samples too

Answer (score 0):

If you keep `http://` in target URI then it will indeed be full redirect.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ftp|mail)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!domain/).*)$ domain/%1/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^domain/([\w-]+)/news/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ news.php?domain=$1&category=$4&news=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([\w-]+)/category/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ category.php?domain=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([\w-]+)/gallery/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ gallery.php?domain=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^domain/([\w-]+)/video/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ video.php?domain=$1&category=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^domain/(.+)/?$ index.php?domain=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser and where is this htaccess located?

Comment: http://tamil.example.com  and it was located in public html which is the server root. and it shows 500 error page as it o now.

Comment: Earlier you wrote forbidden error and now saying 500 error. Check your Apache error.log for the reason of error.

Comment: forget to change example.com with mine. after that i had found 500 error. I thought the reason behind that one is because i have htaccess file in my main domain. Your's one redirecting it to tamil.sample.com/domain/.. etc. So i dont have files in that. i want to serve all files from my main domain i.e www. That's why i added http:// in that

Comment: These rules must be placed in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` and for 500 error you need to check Apache error.log